# Equally and centered distribute data point in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Sorry if the title is not quite right. I want to plot 2 data points with error bar as 2 columns and each one is in the center of each column in the figure. What I've got now it seems far left and right.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = ["lower", "higher"]
y = [1, 2]
dy = [0.2, 0.3]

ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr = dy)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And here is what I want it looks like.

[image]

Comment: One way is to set the limits of the x-axis.

Comment: `plt.margins(0.5)`?

Comment: thank you all, it's the correct way